# jQuery Append and Remove

Tags: jquery, append

I am trying to use this jQuery to append some HTML and then unappend it

```
if( !(jQuery(check).hasClass('selected'))){
    jQuery(this).append('<span class="selected">&nbsp;</span>');
   }
```

How am I able to do this and also live update it ? I am just trying to add this element when a user "clicks" on or "off" ?

i.e. if check does not have the class "Selected" - append - else remove ?

Comment: could you provide some html too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your question was kind of vague and lacked markup I used a basic checkbox example for the demo. I've included a link to a live demo at jsFiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/yvb5d/1/)**

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test" /> Check me

<div id="items"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#test").bind('click', function(){

  var $t = $(this);

  if($t.is(':checked')){
    // append item
    $('#items').append('<span class="selected">I was recently appended.</span>');
  }else{
    // empty div and remove it from DOM (empty helps with memory leak issues with remove() )
    $('span', '#items').empty().remove();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe a more better approach might be to store the result of each append to an array or a variable and loop through that when you remove the elements. For a single element,

```
// Appending
var ele = $('<span>', {
    html: 'nbsp;', 
    class: 'selected'
}).appendTo(container);

// Removing
ele.remove();
```

If you're doing this from within an event handler, the variable `ele` should be defined in the outside scope, so that it is accessible afterwards. For multiple items:

```
// Appending
var ele = [];
ele.push($('<span>', {
    html: 'nbsp;', 
    class: 'selected'
}).appendTo(container));

// Removing
for(var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++){
    ele[i].remove();
}
```

Again, the array `ele` should be defined outside of the scope of any event handlers. Otherwise, the other answers to this question will work too.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#check').click(function() {
    var check = jQuery(this);

    if ( !check.hasClass('selected') ) {
        jQuery('#mydiv').append('<span class="selected">&nbsp;</span>');
        check.addClass('selected');
    } else {
        jQuery('#mydiv span.selected').remove();
        check.removeClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to add span tag there. 
then, the code can be short like this.

```
$("#check").click(function(){
    $(this).hasClass('selected') ? $(this).removeClass('selected') : $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```